# What exactly is the difference between IBDesignable and IBInspectable in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

After searching online I found that, if we declare a property inside a custom view as @IBInspectable, that property can be altered in the IB attribute inspector.

But my question is what is the use of @IBDesignable. Even if I don't declare a class as @ IBDesignable, Im able to see the live rendering of the @IBInspectable properties

Answer (score 3):

`IBDesignable` is user defined run time. Mean that if any `IBDesignable` view is rendered on the storyboard, you will find the view and change the value of the `IBInspectable` property, this will directly reflect on the storyboard without running the app.

`IBInspectable` is run time property, this works as key coding value. You can't find the change in storyboard, it will be applied in the run time.

Answer (score 1):

The live rendering of a custom view should stop once you remove `@IBDesignable`. But sometimes this does not happen immediately.

If you remove `@IBDesignable`, then, close and reopen Xcode.
You should **not** see any live rendering the custom view directly in the canvas.